# How to create a CLR function for SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to write a CLR function to convert old data. I really do not have any knowledge about doing something like this. I really do not know where to start. Can someone help me and tell me the steps? Do I need to create a C function project, etc.?

Comment: i found this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17562/ASCII-Multibyte-to-Unicode-Conversion but i do not know where to start.

Comment: It seems like you are focusing on the technology rather than task. Figure out what you need to do, break it down by logical tasks and start searching. When you actually write code that does not work, then post a question on this web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in C#.

Read the MSDN documentation for CLR functions on the Microsoft website.

Create CLR Functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx

How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

These sites provide examples in C# with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

1. You want a new SQLProject (from vs)
2. Add a stored procedure
3. Code your changes
4. deploy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=VS.80).aspx